# How to store form data into localStorage after form validation with the help of Formik & Yup

Tags: local-storage, formik, yup

How can i store the four input form data into localstorage after validating the form using formik and Yup.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "validating the form" ? Is this when you click on submit, or when you type something and having real-time validation ?
Could you provide us some code ? It's hard to help you if we don't know what you are working on exactly.

If you use `<Formik />` component, you can pass the `onSubmit` prop which will be triggered when you click on submit component. Then you will be able to store the data in localStorage.

Comment: You just create simple  form  with 4 input field like FName, LName, FatherName, DOB and validate that form using Formik and Yub and after validation store the input field into localstorage with the help of onSubmit function.

Comment: I have done it but i an not able to store user data into localStorage.